# List inside Class Inheriting from Interfaces - Add to list from within class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, ienumerable, ilist

Excuse the poor title, couldn't quite explain my issue in as few words. I'm trying to make a simple calendar app within some rough guidelines I've been given which have led me this far.

I have a class called **Apts**, inheriting from an interface **IApts**, which itself inherits from another interface **IApt**. My code is as follows:

***IApt***

```
public interface IApt
{
    DateTime Start { get; }
    int Length { get; }
    string Description{ get; }
    bool Occurs(DateTime date);
}
```

***IApts***

```
public interface IApts : IList<IApt>
{
    bool Load();
    bool Save();
    IEnumerable<IApt> GetAptsOnDate(DateTime date);
}
```

***Apts*** *(Cut down to the minimum of course)*

```
class Apts: IApts
{
    public List<IApt> myAppointments = new List<IApt>();

    public Apts()
    {
        // Constructor must be empty - guideliness
    }

    public bool Load()
    {
        //Code to load appointment data from file to variables below
        string startTime = x;
        string lengthTime = y;
        string description = z;

        IApt loadedAppointment = new IApt(aptStartDate, aptLength, aptDescription);
                myAppointments.Add(loadedAppointment);
    }

#IList Methods
#IEnumerable Methods
}
```

Hopefully my code snippets give you the idea of what I'm trying to achieve here. I will create an instance of the Apts class from my mainForm in order to hold all of my appointments as follows:

```
IApts _Appointments = new Apts();
```

I want to do 2 things now. I want to add items from my mainForm of type IApt (Is this even possible? :S). I also want my Load() method to be able to be called from my mainForm once I've created the instance in order to populate the list myAppointments with appointments whose contents will come from a simple text file storage.

Could someone advise me if what I'm trying to do is even possible? Everything else is in place, I just need to be able to access thelist which is created when I create the instance of Apts and to add objects to it of type IApt.

OR would it make sense to create another class, perhaps named Apt because creating a new object of type Apts would be creating another list..? I'm hoping someone is following me heh.. My head is spinning!

Comment: Have you even tried it yourself? The intelligence alone should tell you its possible to do..

Comment: If you're referring to creating another class, Apt, then yes I know it's possible but I'm wondering if it's necessary as the guidelines I'm working within seem to suggest that only the Apts class is needed. I'm very much a novice here so I was hoping someone with a bit more experience could point me in the right direction so I know I'm at least on the right lines with what I've done so far :)

Comment: Intelligence was a bad spell check, I ment visual studio intellisense. Sorry if it sounded rude, Mybad lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface IApt
{
    DateTime Start { set;get; }
    int Length { set;get; }
    string Description{ set;get; }
    bool Occurs(DateTime date);
}
```

Add this property to the interface IApts

```
List<IApt> myAppointments {set;get;}
```

Implement this interface eg:

```
public class Apt : IApt
{
    public DateTime Start { set;get; }
    public int Length { set;get; }
    public string Description{ set;get; }
    public bool Occurs(DateTime date){

    }
}
```

Then

```
 IApts _Appointments = new Apts();

    IApt apt = new Apt();
    apt.Start=...
    apt.Length=...
    _Appointments.myAppointments.Add(apt);
_Appointments.Load();
```

Don't want to pass judgement on your naming conventions as long as they stay the same through out the code but public members are normally UpperCamelCase and private are either prefixed with _lowerCamelCase or lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Add List<IApt> myAppointments {set;get;} to the interface? Or he doesn't want to change the interface?

Comment: Thanks, my guidelines were wrong *sigh*. Creating the Apt class was the solution! Will check back over those naming conventions *oops*!

Answer (score 1):

You should create an `Add` method and implement it:

```
public interface IApts
{
    bool Load();
    bool Save();
    void Add(IApt appointment);
    IEnumerable<IApt> GetAptsOnDate(DateTime date);
}

class Apts: IApts
{
    private List<IApt> myAppointments = new List<IApt>();

    public void Add(IApt appointment)
    {
        this.myAppointments.Add(appointment);
    }

    // rest of class omitted for brevity
}
```

By the way, you probably want to make `myAppointments` private. You're exposing too much with it being public.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already created an add method as I'm inheriting from IList, though I didn't make it clear above that the IList methods were all already implemented.

Comment: @Jamie4840 so why aren't you just calling that `Add` method to add items? You really should hide your class' implementation from the rest of your program.